# HUGE - SVID mode specifies returning this large value instead of infinity

Tags: c++, c

In my Ubuntu 14.04 machine, `/usr/include/math.h` contains the following definition

```
/* SVID mode specifies returning this large value instead of infinity.  */
# define HUGE           3.40282347e+38F
```

This is absent in my Ubuntu 18.04 machine's `/usr/include/math.h`

What is this `HUGE` variable for, where was it used and why was it removed?

Comment: https://doc.ecoscentric.com/ref/c-and-math-library-overview.html#math-library-compatibility-modes